# Renderer - onElementChanged called multiple times

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a simple page in my app, where I have a ListView, some entries in the ViewCells and a button at the bottom.

The source code for it can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b2jzl7v9fnxqrng/AAANh2naAg2t9Kr6gN1lUsrGa?dl=0

The problem is, that when an item has an amount the button is covering the following entries (when the keyboard is shown), so the user can't see, what he/she is writing (I only want to show the button, if any entries have an amount). 
 
As it is now it is correct, but in somehow, an event is occuring a lot of times, and it ends in a deadlock.

Do anybody have an idea of how to fix it?

At this moment, I can't update to Xamarin Forms 2, as the SignaturePad rely on Xamarin Forms 1.5

As I see it, the problem is, that this is called more than once per element.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
   base.OnElementChanged(e);

   EKEntry base_entry = (EKEntry)this.Element;

   if (Control != null && base_entry != null)
   {
      if (base_entry.ForceBackgroundColor.HasValue)
      {
         if (base_entry.ForceBackgroundColor.Value == Color.White)
         Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
      }

      if (base_entry.DisableScrolling)
      {
         var activity = Forms.Context as Activity;
         if (activity != null)
         {
            activity.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustNothing);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I tried to set the softinputmode in Focuschange but without success.

The output in the console is

```
06-02 07:54:55.296 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26975): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
06-02 07:54:55.301 W/View    (26975): requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1e1539da V.E..... R....... 0,0-1080,1776} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
06-02 07:54:55.302 W/View    (26975): requestLayout() improperly called by md5282f1122c1313907b9bf274dd2c2f344.EntryEditText{b74e164 VFED..CL .F...... 0,0-180,150} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
06-02 07:54:55.302 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26975): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
06-02 07:54:55.731 W/View    (26975): requestLayout() improperly called by md5282f1122c1313907b9bf274dd2c2f344.EntryEditText{19e1247d VFED..CL ......ID 0,0-180,150} during layout: running second layout pass
06-02 07:54:55.731 W/View    (26975): requestLayout() improperly called by md5282f1122c1313907b9bf274dd2c2f344.EntryEditText{b74e164 VFED..CL .F....ID 0,0-180,150} during layout: running second layout pass
06-02 07:54:56.054 I/Choreographer(26975): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-02 07:54:56.064 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26975): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
06-02 07:54:56.064 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26975): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
06-02 07:54:56.065 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26975): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
06-02 07:54:56.069 W/View    (26975): requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1e1539da V.E..... R....... 0,0-1080,1776} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
06-02 07:54:56.069 W/View    (26975): requestLayout() improperly called by md5282f1122c1313907b9bf274dd2c2f344.EntryEditText{b74e164 VFED..CL .F...... 0,0-180,150} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
06-02 07:54:56.069 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26975): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
06-02 07:54:56.406 W/View    (26975): requestLayout() improperly called by md5282f1122c1313907b9bf274dd2c2f344.EntryEditText{19e1247d VFED..CL ......ID 0,0-180,150} during layout: running second layout pass
06-02 07:54:56.406 W/View    (26975): requestLayout() improperly called by md5282f1122c1313907b9bf274dd2c2f344.EntryEditText{b74e164 VFED..CL .F....ID 0,0-180,150} during layout: running second layout pass
06-02 07:54:57.275 I/art     (26975): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 86858(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 148MB/164MB, paused 1.575ms total 41.493ms
06-02 07:54:57.296 D/Mono    (26975): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 3788 num_hash_entries 100267 sccs size 47151 init 0.00ms df1 285.92ms sort 59.40ms dfs2 126.79ms setup-cb 10.71ms free-data 237.97ms links 176105/176105/1213352/28 dfs passes 280160/223256
06-02 07:54:57.296 D/Mono    (26975): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 334.55ms, total 334.65ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 8176K major 8176K los 2320K
06-02 07:54:57.599 I/Choreographer(26975): Skipped 89 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-02 07:54:57.605 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26975): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
06-02 07:54:57.605 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26975): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
06-02 07:54:57.607 W/View    (26975): requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1e1539da V.E..... R....... 0,0-1080,1776} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
06-02 07:54:57.607 W/View    (26975): requestLayout() improperly called by md5282f1122c1313907b9bf274dd2c2f344.EntryEditText{b74e164 VFED..CL .F...... 0,0-180,150} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
06-02 07:54:57.607 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26975): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
06-02 07:54:57.926 W/View    (26975): requestLayout() improperly called by md5282f1122c1313907b9bf274dd2c2f344.EntryEditText{19e1247d VFED..CL ......ID 0,0-180,150} during layout: running second layout pass
06-02 07:54:57.926 W/View    (26975): requestLayout() improperly called by md5282f1122c1313907b9bf274dd2c2f344.EntryEditText{b74e164 VFED..CL .F....ID 0,0-180,150} during layout: running second layout pass
```

A screenshot of how it looks like, when I have only entered an amount
[image: A screenshot of how it looks like, when I have only entered an amount]

A screenshot of how it looks like when the output above occurs (the keyboard does not show up)
[image: A screenshot of how it looks like when the output above occurs (the keyboard does not show up)]

When an entry is focused, I scroll to the item to show it as the 1st item in the ListView using `_lstMaterials.ScrollTo(item, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);` and afterwards I check if the text is null or empty, as it then have to refresh the cursor (by setting the text to " ", as the cursor sometimes do not appear).

**UPDATE**
I figured out, that it may occur because `Focused` and `Unfocused` events are called multiple times. But I can't see, why this is happening, and how to prevent it.

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of your code and format them.  Posting links to an external resource is highly discouraged.

Comment: Screenshots would be beneficial also.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this post is quite old I was facing the same issue.
This helped in my case, maybe it helps others too:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null && e.NewElement !=null)
            {
                return;
            }
           // your stuff here
         }
```

Note that this can cause issues if you use NavigationPage and just Pop a Page from stack since the OldElement might not be null anymore, so your custom adjustments might not be called.

Probably not the best solution but as mentioned it could help in simple cases.